# Definition and Measurment of Energy and Heat in Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

The concept of work is clear from mechanics, where $dW=F\cdot dx$, leading to $dW=PdV$. Also different forms of energy are defined in mechanics, e.g., $E=\frac{1}{2}m v^2$, etc. How are the energy and heat defined and measured in thermodynamics?

Because once we define them independently, we can state the first law of thermodynamics, $d E=\delta Q+\delta W$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the experimental observations behind the first principle of thermodynamics?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87080/)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8522/2451 and links therein.